# JavaScript functions prevent C# functions from being executed?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

On my aspx page I have two buttons.  One calls some javascript and the other calls a C# function on the code-page.  When I call the javascript file in the head of the document, the JavaScript function works well but the C# does not.  Clicking on the button does not do anything.  If I remove the javascript call then the C# function works normally.

How can I overcome this?  It seems as if it is expecting to find the C# function within the JavaScript file.

ASP:

```
<head>
<script src="MyFunctions.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<asp:Button id="btn1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="buttonSumbit_Click" />
<asp:Button id="btn2" Text="Show" runat="server" OnClientClick="buttonShow_Click()" />
</body>
```

C#:

```
protected void buttonSumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//SOME CODE HERE
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function buttonShow_Click()
{
//SOME CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: If one calls javascript and other calls c# do you click both the buttons at the same time !?

Comment: The `language` attribute of `script` elements has been deprecated long ago.

Comment: are you missing some code here?? or this is the total code present in the .aspx page?

Comment: I don't click both buttons at the same time.  The javascript function sets a div's display attribute from 'hidden' to 'block', and the C# function writes data to database.

Comment: Yes there is some code missing, such as <form runat="server">

Answer (score 2):

You need to put all Asp.Net server controls inside a `<form runat="server"></form>` tag

Comment: all controls are within the <form> tags.  The C# functions work perfectly when I don't have the JavaScript.js file linked to the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your javascript function call to be like this

```
<asp:Button id="btn2" Text="Show" runat="server" OnClientClick="return buttonShow_Click()" />
```

and make sure that your javascript function returns true so postback (execute C# function) happens. If your javascript function return false, postback to server won't happen.

Comment: My C# functions are still not available.  I've tried removing the button with the javascript on-click event.  The other buttons still do not work.  They only work when I remove the line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript.js"></script>`

Comment: If so can you please share your Javascript.js file?

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to use this for calling javascript functions:

```
OnClientClick="if(!hidepopup())return false;"
```

you can also call javascript functions from codebehind:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "jsfunction();", true);
```